# how to convert rows to columns from presented table in sql developer?

Tags: oracle, rows

I would like to make data in this table more optimise. I have now like this:

[image: My initial data table]

And I tried

```
SELECT *
  FROM T_TEST
PIVOT (
  MAX(cnt) FOR ASSIGNMENT_ROLE IN ('2nd case','1st case','3rd case')
);
```

I got this result which has nulls and doesn't work for me

[image: The result of my query]

Instead I would like something like this:

[image: The result I wanted]

Comment: You showed what you don't want (the 2nd screenshot), but you missed to show what you do want.

Comment: please, can you give me example? thank you

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B): "The DATE data type **stores date and time information**. Although date and time information can be represented in both character and number data types, the DATE data type has special associated properties. **For each DATE value**, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, **hour, minute, and second**." Use `trunc(date_value)`

Comment: max each value pivoted and group by your date (DT)  Note however, if you have to filter any of these values, your index usage is 0.  For example: `SELECT DT, Max(FIRST_CASE), SECOND_CASE, THIRD_CASE
FROM (YOUR QUERY HERE)
GROUP BY DT`  gives you results; but if you add a where clause on first, second or third case; it can't use any indexes.  Note your query here is the query used to get the NULL values  It's just a wrapper around your quey giving you the null values.  You could also use a CTE instead

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a table with at least some date column and the assignment_role. For example:

```sql
create table role_whatever(
  log_date date, 
  assignment_role varchar2(30), 
  whatever varchar2(42));
```

Then you can get the desired report with:

```sql
select *
from (
select assignment_role,trunc(log_date) dt
from role_whatever
) pivot (
  count(*) for assignment_role in (
    '1st case' as FIRST_CASE,
    '2nd case' as SECOND_CASE,
    '3rd case' as THIRD_CASE))
order by dt;
```

Note, since the log_date column may contain a time part, I used trunc() on it.

Test data for this table was generated with:

```sql
insert into role_whatever
  select date '2022-07-15' + dbms_random.value(1,5) log_date,
  decode(round(dbms_random.value(1,3)),1,'1st',2,'2nd',3,'3rd') || ' case' assignment_role,
  dbms_random.string('A',10) whatever
  from dual 
  connect by level < 10000;
```

If you have a table with the aggregated result as shown in your first image, then this query gives the same result:

```sql
select *
from (
    select assignment_role,dt,cnt
    from role_aggregated
) pivot (
 sum(cnt) for assignment_role in (
    '1st case' as FIRST_CASE,
    '2nd case' as SECOND_CASE,
    '3rd case' as THIRD_CASE))
order by dt;
```

The table above was created with:

```sql
create table role_aggregated as 
select count(*) cnt,assignment_role,trunc(log_date) dt
from role_whatever
group by assignment_role,trunc(log_date);
```